# DCDG Dart Diagrams: Unhandled exception: Bad state: Unable to find the context to foldername\env.dart

Tags: dart, class-diagram, dart-pub

I have been trying to generate dart diagrams for my code but the below error:

```
C:\Users\Foldername\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin>dart pub global run dcdg
C:\Users\Foldername\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin\lib

Unhandled exception:

Bad state: Unable to find the context to C:\Users\Foldername\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin\lib\.env.dart
#0      AnalysisContextCollectionImpl.contextFor (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/analysis_context_collection.dart:106:5)
#1      findClassElements (package:dcdg/src/find_class_elements.dart:46:39)
#2      main (file:///C:/Users/Foldername/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dcdg-4.0.1/bin/dcdg.dart:35:25)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

1- I have activated the package.

2- I have updated it to the latest.

3- Environment variables are correctly set.

I still don't understand why does it not allow me to create class diagrams for my code. Anyone has any answers?

Comment: found anything helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I think that probably in your project are dependencies that use code-generation (with `build_runner`) like: `freezed`, `auto_route`, `localizely` or `hive`. Package `dcdg` at the moment (ver. 4.1.0) have issues for generating PlantUML file for such projects. If you want to use `dcdg` you need to refactor your code and remove such dependencies.

[Here is github issue related to your case.](https://github.com/glesica/dcdg.dart/issues/52#issuecomment-1378593030)